# Issues in Plotting Intraday OHLC Chart with Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot OHLC candlestick chart (1Min) for complete one day and want to show 'Hours' as Major locator and Min as minor locator.
Hour locator should be displayed as till end of data
Major Locator
09:00
10:00
11:00 and so on.

[image]

I am not able to understand what error I am doing and why time is starting from 22:00 and OHLC candles are not visible.

If you can also help with volume overlay on ohlc chart it would be a great help.[link to data file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4iD4lT8-7J2ckhNcFIxR0E3YTA/view?usp=sharing)

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.gridspec as grd
from matplotlib.transforms import Bbox
from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc, volume_overlay3, volume_overlay
#from matplotlib.finance import candlestick
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, WeekdayLocator, DayLocator, MONDAY, HourLocator, MinuteLocator


import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def plot_underlying_hft_data(filename):


    #Read the data and filtered out the required rows and columns
    print("Reading File.. ", filename)
    tempdata = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col = ['Date'])
    tempdata = tempdata.loc[(tempdata.index == '2016-09-16')]

    tempdata['Datetime'] =  pd.to_datetime(tempdata['Datetime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    print(tempdata)

    HourLocator

    hour = HourLocator()    
    minute = MinuteLocator()
    hourformatter = DateFormatter('%H:%M') 

    #tempdata['Datetime'] = tempdata['Datetime'].apply(lambda datetimevar : datetime)

    tempdata['DatetimeNum'] = mdates.date2num(tempdata['Datetime'].dt.to_pydatetime())

    quotes = [tuple(x) for x in tempdata[['DatetimeNum', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']].to_records(index=False)]

    #print(quotes)    
    title_name_ohlc = 'OHLC Intraday Chart'
    #print(title_name_ohlc)
    plt.figure(figsize = (12,6))
    #plt.title(title_name_ohlc)
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,1), (0,0), axisbg='w')

    ax1.set_ylabel('Price', fontsize=12, fontweight = 'bold')
    ax1.set_title(title_name_ohlc, fontsize=14, fontweight = 'bold')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Price', fontsize=12, fontweight = 'bold')
    ax1.set_title(title_name_ohlc, fontsize=14, fontweight = 'bold')
    print(tempdata['DatetimeNum'].min(), tempdata['DatetimeNum'].max())
    ax1.set_ylim(bottom = tempdata['DatetimeNum'].min(), top = tempdata['DatetimeNum'].max())

    ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(hour)
    ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minute)
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hourformatter)
    #ax1.grid(True)
    candlestick_ohlc(ax1, quotes, width=1, colorup='g', colordown='r', alpha = 1.0)
    plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')
    plt.show()

plot_underlying_hft_data("data.csv")

        #print(tempdata.head(5))
```

Answer (score 3):

I was doing mistake in defining the xlimits and width in the plotting of graph. I fixed after reading documentation and some hit and trial and got the output as desired. [image]

```
def plot_underlying_hft_data(filename):


#Read the data and filtered out the required rows and columns
print("Reading File.. ", filename)
tempdata = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col = ['Date'])
tempdata = tempdata.loc[(tempdata.index == '2016-09-16')].tail(751)
print(tempdata.head(5))
tempdata.set_index(['Datetime'], inplace = True)
print(tempdata.head(5))

#tempdata['Datetime'] =  pd.to_datetime(tempdata['Datetime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
#print(tempdata)

#hour = HourLocator(interval = 1)    
minute = MinuteLocator(interval = 30)
hourformatter = DateFormatter('%H:%M') 

#tempdata['Datetime'] = tempdata['Datetime'].apply(lambda datetimevar : datetime)
tempdata["Datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(tempdata.index)
tempdata.Datetime = mdates.date2num(tempdata.Datetime.dt.to_pydatetime())
#print(tempdata.head(5))

quotes = [tuple(x) for x in tempdata[['Datetime', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']].to_records(index=False)]

#print(quotes)    
title_name_ohlc = 'OHLC Intraday Chart'
#print(title_name_ohlc)
plt.figure(figsize = (18,10))
#plt.title(title_name_ohlc)
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,1), (0,0), axisbg='w')

ax1.set_ylabel('Price', fontsize=12, fontweight = 'bold')
ax1.set_title(title_name_ohlc, fontsize=14, fontweight = 'bold')
ax1.set_ylabel('Price', fontsize=12, fontweight = 'bold')
ax1.set_xlabel('Time', fontsize=12, fontweight = 'bold')
ax1.set_title(title_name_ohlc, fontsize=14, fontweight = 'bold')
#print(tempdata['DatetimeNum'].min(), tempdata['DatetimeNum'].max())
ax1.set_xlim(tempdata['Datetime'].min(), tempdata['Datetime'].max())

ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(minute)
#ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(minute)
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hourformatter)
ax1.axhline(y=262.32, linewidth=1.5, color='g', alpha = 0.7, linestyle = "dashed")
ax1.axhline(y=260.33, linewidth=2, color='g', alpha = 0.7, linestyle = "dashed")
ax1.axhline(y=258.17, linewidth=2.5, color='g', alpha = 0.7, linestyle = "dashed")
ax1.axhline(y=256.18, linewidth=3, color='b', alpha = 1, linestyle = "dashed")
ax1.axhline(y=254.02, linewidth=2.5, color='r', alpha = 0.7, linestyle = "dashed")
ax1.axhline(y=252.03, linewidth=2, color='r', alpha = 0.7, linestyle = "dashed")
ax1.axhline(y=249.87, linewidth=1.5, color='r', alpha = 0.7, linestyle = "dashed")

#['256.18', '254.02', '252.03', '249.87', '258.17', '260.33', '262.32']
ax1.grid(True)

#ax1.grid(True)
candlestick_ohlc(ax1, quotes, width = 1/(24*60*2.5), alpha = 1.0, colorup = 'g', colordown ='r')
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), horizontalalignment='center')

pad = 0.25
yl = ax1.get_ylim()
print(yl)
ax1.set_ylim(yl[0]-(yl[1]-yl[0])*pad,yl[1]*1.005)

Datetime = [x[0] for x in quotes]
Datetime = np.asarray(Datetime)
Volume = [x[5] for x in quotes]
Volume = np.asarray(Volume)

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.set_position(matplotlib.transforms.Bbox([[0.125,0.125],[0.9,0.27]]))
width = 1/(24*60*4)
ax2.bar(Datetime, Volume, color='blue', width = width, alpha = 0.75)
ax2.set_ylim([0, ax2.get_ylim()[1] * 1])
ax2.set_ylabel('Volume', fontsize=12, fontweight = 'bold')
yticks = ax2.get_yticks()
ax2.set_yticks(yticks[::1])
#ax2.grid(True)
#report_pdf.savefig(pad_inches=0.5, bbox_inches= 'tight')
#plt.close()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Would you mind re-upload your file or a similar file? The link doesn't work anymore. I'm facing a similar problem here. Thanks.